# Difference Between Two List Elements in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a data class as below in Kotlin.

```
data class ProductData(
    val code: String,
    var value: Double)
```

There are two list for the above data class as

```
lstToday: List<ProductData> contains such as
("P1", 110)
("P2", 109)
("P3", 102)
("P4", 110)
..... 100+ records

and

lstYesterday: List<ProductData> contains such as
("P1", 112)
("P2", 109)
("P3", 110)
("P4", 90)
..... 100+ records
```

Both has the identical and exact number of records.
The output I am looking for is as below.

Output 1: Difference between yesterday and today

```
lstDifference: List<ProductData> contains such as
("P1", -2)
("P2", 0)
("P3", 8)
("P4", -20)
..... 100+ records
```

Output 2: Today Price and Difference between yesterday and today
using the data class below.

```
data class ProductDisplayData(
    val code: String,
    var value: Double,
    var diff: Double

)

With list as below
lstDifference: List<ProductData> contains such as
("P1", 112, -2)
("P2", 109, 0)
("P3", 110, 8)
("P4", 90, -20)
..... 100+ records
```

Can this be achieved using any functions Kotlin, or is it we have loop each element and get the result.

Thanks

Comment: If you change your data structure to a hashmap, this can be done quite easily by having key-value pairs which are the code and the value.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is not the most efficient solution. We're talking 0n ish. This could definitely be optimized. To note, this is fault tolerant of the code itself not being included in both days, and assumes 0 for a non-existent value between days.
Trying to guarantee that both data sets will always be the same, is going to be more maintenance than writing code that will tolerate that mistake.

```
data class ProductData(
    val code: String,
    var value: Double
)

val dayOne = listOf(
    ProductData("P1", 110.0),
    ProductData("P2", 109.0),
    ProductData("P3", 102.0),
    ProductData("P4", 110.0),
    ProductData("P5", 105.0),
    ProductData("P6", 104.0),
    ProductData("P8", 32.0) // Not in set 2
)

val dayTwo = listOf(
    ProductData("P1", 110.0),
    ProductData("P2", 109.0),
    ProductData("P3", 102.0),
    ProductData("P4", 90.0),
    ProductData("P5", 49.0),
    ProductData("P6", 123.0),
    ProductData("P7", 239.0) // Not in set 1
)

fun periodDataDifference(dayOne: List<ProductData>, dayTwo: List<ProductData>): List<ProductData> {
    val mapOne = dayOne.associate { it.code to it.value }
    val mapTwo = dayTwo.associate { it.code to it.value }
    val keys = mapOne.keys + mapTwo.keys

    return keys.map { key ->
        val first = mapOne[key] ?: 0.0
        val second = mapTwo[key] ?: 0.0

        ProductData(key, second - first)
    }
}

val out = periodDataDifference(dayOne, dayTwo)

println(out)
/*
    [ProductData(code=P1, value=0.0), 
    ProductData(code=P2, value=0.0), 
    ProductData(code=P3, value=0.0), 
    ProductData(code=P4, value=-20.0), 
    ProductData(code=P5, value=-56.0), 
    ProductData(code=P6, value=19.0), 
    ProductData(code=P8, value=-32.0), // Set 1 only
    ProductData(code=P7, value=239.0)] // Set 2 only
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

If today and yesterday lists are gonna be same size this is the quickest solution I have

```
    val lstYesterday: List<ProductData> = listOf(
        ProductData("P1", 112.0),
        ProductData("P2", 109.0),
        ProductData("P3", 110.0)
    )
    val lstToday: List<ProductData> = listOf(
        ProductData("P1", 110.0),
        ProductData("P2", 109.0),
        ProductData("P3", 102.0)
    )
    val lstDifference: MutableList<ProductData> = mutableListOf()

    for ((index,j) in lstToday.withIndex()){
        val code = lstToday[index].code
        val value = lstToday[index].value-lstYesterday[index].value
        lstDifference.add(ProductData(code,value))
    }
```

Comment: That's fine until someone removes a product. Or adds a new one. Or sorts them differently…